# chain setState multiple times

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hello React specialists,

I'm working on an application and I ended up chaining setState for 3 times like this:

```
this.setState({}, () => {
    // first call back 
    this.setState({}, () => {
        // second call back
        this.setState();
    })
})
```

Now, state logic is working fine, I faced some unexpected unexplained behaviour, like: inputs UI are not changing although the state does. and some other stuff with no reason why it's happening.

question is:  have you expected problems while using this chain ?? why it's bad to do this ??  do you think that this chaining might be the root of the problem ??

Comment: Why do you need to chain, rather than just update in one go by putting all the new properties in a single `setState` call? I can't say if the chaining is the reason for the problems you mention (you don't give enough detail to even guess as to the cause), but it certainly seems very inefficient.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal reproducible example of the unexpected behavior you are experiencing? Honestly, i can't understand why do you have such nested calls to `this.setState`. If the new state depends on the previous state, use the functional form of the `this.setState` instead of nesting calls to `this.setState`.